# Significato e uso degli accenti (diacritici, gravi e acuti) sulle vocali di parole italiane

Tags: grammar, orthography, accents

Le vocali italiane possono portare degli [accenti](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_italiano). Vorrei sapere come faccio a sapere quando usare l'accento grave o l'accento acuto. Che differenza c'è tra i due? So che per esempio la terza persona singolare del presente indicativo del verbo essere si scrive 'è' con l'accento grave, mentre 'perché' si scrive con l'accento acuto. Il [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/) è bravo a elencare le differenze, ma mi confonde un po' dato che usa l'accento grave anche per denotare lo stress, e dato che questo stress non si scrive nello scritto, talvolta non so se l'accento che appare nel Treccani indica stress o grafia.

Qualcuno mi potrebbe cortesemente elencare quali sono le regole grammaticali e sintattiche pertinenti ai vari accenti sulle vocali italiane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come @DaG ha detto, le regole complete sull'uso dell'accento in italiano sono sull'Enciclopedia Treccani. Possiamo però cercare di fare un riassunto delle regole più importanti sull'uso dell'accento grafico.

> È obbligatorio segnare l'accento nei seguenti casi:
>
> - In parole polisillabiche tronche (cioè, con l'accento fonico sull'ultima sillaba): per esempio, *caffè*, *parlerà*, *perché*, *così*, *arriverò*.
> - In alcune parole monosillabiche che contengono due vocali perché, senza l'accento grafico, potrebbero essere lette come parole piane: ad esempio, *può*, *giù*, *più*, *già*.
> - In alcune parole monosillabiche per non confonderle con omonimi (parole con la stessa forma fonica e grafia simile): per esempio, *è* (verbo), *sì* (affermazione), *là* (avverbio), *lì* (avverbio), *sé* (pronome) sono distinte da *e* (congiunzione), *si* (pronome), *la* (articolo o pronome), *li* (pronome), *se* (congiunzione).
>
> La forma grafica standard dell'accento in italiano è quella chiamata “grave” (`), eccetto sulle "e" che hanno un suono chiuso, sulle quali si scrive l'accento chiamato "acuto" (′).

Fonti: Maria Cristina Peccianti, *Grammatica italiana per stranieri* (Giunti Editori, 2013) e [Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accento-grafico_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/).

Answer (score 3):

Penso che nessuno qui possa essere più esauriente delle voci dell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano sull'[accento](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accento_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) in generale e sull'[accento grafico](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accento-grafico_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/) (o segnaccento). Le hai lette? Poi ti potremo rispondere su eventuali dubbi che ti siano rimasti.